# I have to send a mail if a number in a file is > of a value

Tags: awk, grep

I have to sent a mail if in a text file, there is a value >20.

text file example

- red        10
- brown      15
- blue       21

I have to send a mail where I inform that blue is over 21 attempts

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you provide a [MCVE] of your tries and explain what does not work ?

Comment: I run a query where I capture element with a problem in a 15 minutes. The file it is structured with name and repetition of the problem. If the repeated count it is bigger then 20 I would like to send the mail. So I can send the mail but I can't trigger it and i don't know how to copy the information into it

Answer (score 0):

With the following:

```
 awk '
 BEGIN {XX="";
    print "Subject:...\nFrom:... <test@gmail.com>\nTo:test@gmail.com"
 } {
    if($2>20) {
         XX=$1;
         exit(0)
    }
 }  
 END {
    if(XX!="")printf("%s is over 21 attemps\015\n",XX)
 }' file.tmp > >(/usr/lib/sendmail -t test@gmail.com)
```

The `BEGIN` section writes the header of the mail and initializes a variable XX (empty).

The `if($2>20)` catch the condition you want and, if true, changes the value of XX then exit

The `END` section writes the end of the mail if XX is no longer empty

Then you nest this into a a command that redirect the message to sendmail if something is written and exit  in other case:

```
{ awk 'BEGIN{XX="";print "Subject:...\nFrom:... <test@gmail.com>\nTo:test@gmail.com"} {if($2>20) {XX=$1;exit(0)}}  END{if(XX!=""){printf("%s is over 21 attemps\015\n",XX)}else{exit(1)} }' file.tmp || exit;} > >(/usr/lib/sendmail -t test@gmail.com)
```

Note that `|| exit`  is active only if awk exists with a value >0 (i.e with the `exit(1)` of the `END` section)

Original example at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246863/awk-send-email-if